# HP MicroServer - HPE Smart Array E208i-p SR Gen 10

Tags: raid

I have an HP MicroServer Gen10 with 4x4TB HDD's.
The MicroServer is using hardware RAID "HPE Smart Array E208i-p SR Gen10".

However:

When booting into Ubuntu Server 16.04, the RAID array shows up as 938GB.

[image]

When booting into Ubuntu Desktop (live USB), it shows up correctly as ±10.9TB.

[image]

The interesting thing is that it would be working fine using software raid or as individual drives.

However, I would like to make full use of the RAID controller and it does not seem to be an hardware issue (since it works well in UbuntuDesktop, but not in UbuntuServer.

I'm guessing some form of support is missing in UbuntuServer, but I'm hoping anyone here can shed a light on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E208 (and P408 and P816) use the SmartPQI Drivers from MicroSemi (used to be PMC Sierra).
These drivers were formerly called hpsa (HP Smart Array) and then before that CCISS (Compaq Computers Inc Smart Storage).

My guess is the drivers included in 16 vs 18 are different and the 16 drivers are too old for the Firmware you have in that machine.

If you can, see if these work:

https://storage.microsemi.com/en-us/downloads/ubuntu/ubuntu_16/productid=aha-2100-4i4e&dn=microsemi+adaptec+smarthba+2100-4i4e.php